# No repository found at http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/

Tags: eclipse, azure

I am trying to add an Azure Tool kit on my eclipse and getting the below error -

No repository found at http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/.

I can also see that this URL is no more available -

Error 403 - This web app is stopped.
The web app you have attempted to reach is currently stopped and does not accept any requests. Please try to reload the page or visit it again soon.

Do we have a new URL for downloading the Azure Tool kit for the eclipse?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report. Our Product group is aware of this issue and is working on a resolution.

As a temporary workaround, please use `https://azuredownloads.blob.core.windows.net/eclipse/` to get the latest Azure Toolkit for Eclipse. You can follow further updates about the fix on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/issues/4947).

Also, I noticed that installing via the **Eclipse Marketplace** works without any errors on Eclipse version `2020-12 (4.18.0) Build id: 20201210-1552`.

Here is the detailed article that describes both the installation methods for reference: [Installing the Azure Toolkit for Eclipse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/toolkit-for-eclipse/installation#install-new-software)

Supported Eclipse versions for [Azure Toolkit for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/azure-toolkit-eclipse):

> 2021-03 (4.19), 2020-12 (4.18), 2020-09 (4.17), 2020-06 (4.16), 2020-03 (4.15), 2019-12 (4.14), 2019-09 (4.13), 2019-06 (4.12), 2019-03 (4.11), 2018-12 (4.10), 2018-09 (4.9), Photon (4.8), Oxygen (4.7), Neon (4.6)